# adding data on top of a 3D base map using R

Tags: r, 3d

I am trying to plot a 3D space time cube in R and I want to have a basemap.
I am using rgl library. I know how to plot my data using x, y and z, where z is the time variable. I have also managed to download a map that I want to use as reference from openstreetmap, using the library in R. However, I cannot find a way to plot my data on the map in a 3D environment. I found the following code in several sites and as an answer to a similar question:

```
map3d <- function(map, ...){
if(length(map$tiles)!=1){stop("multiple tiles not implemented") }
nx = map$tiles[[1]]$xres
ny = map$tiles[[1]]$yres
xmin = map$tiles[[1]]$bbox$p1[1]
xmax = map$tiles[[1]]$bbox$p2[1]
ymin = map$tiles[[1]]$bbox$p1[2]
ymax = map$tiles[[1]]$bbox$p2[2]
xc = seq(xmin,xmax,len=ny)
yc = seq(ymin,ymax,len=nx)
colours = matrix(map$tiles[[1]]$colorData,ny,nx)
m = matrix(0,ny,nx)
surface3d(xc,yc,m,col=colours, ...)
}
```

However, I cannot really understand how it works.
Here's my code so far:

```
library(rgl)
library(ggplot2)
library(OpenStreetMap)
map <- openmap(c(53.5,73.6),c(15.7,134.7),type= 'esri-topo')
plot3d(x,y,z, col= colour) # to plot my data
autoplot(map) # to plot the map. though this is 2D
```

Again, I know how to plot my data on a 2D map. Confused with the 3D.
Any hints and tips on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean 'OpenStreetMap' as the package name?

Comment: yes this is the one

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the newish 'show2d' function in 'rgl'.

```
library(rgl)
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(raster)

map <- openmap(c(53.5,73.6),c(15.7,134.7),type= 'esri-topo')

## fake up some xyz
xyz <- expand.grid(x = map$bbox$p1, 
               y = map$bbox$p2, 
               z = 1:4)

plot3d(xyz, col = "black") # to plot my data
```

EDIT: this is wrong, it's only fitted to the bounding box
getting the orientation right is confusing, needs to be check with x, y, z arguments to show2d.

```
show2d(raster::plotRGB(raster(map)))
```

This function captures the normal plot expression, writes it to PNG and then texture maps it onto a quad in the scene.

I can't quite see how to control the position of the quad for the image texture with the x, y, z args - work in progress.

Comment: hi mdsumner. thanks for that. it seems that it is "somehow" working. I have managed to plot my data and basemap in the box. though, the points do not fit on the map as they should be. I assume it has to do with the expand.grid command. could you please provide me some more info on how to fix this? thanks

Comment: If you provide an example of the problem, yes. The georeferencing is a bit loose, but def possible to get it exactly.

Comment: ok here's the exact bbox for my map:
map<-openmap(c(37.2,31),c(34.2,36.8),type= 'esri-topo').
and then here's a sample of my first few rows of the data:
lon                  lat
33.9500167 35.14637
33.94996         35.1463433
33.94999         35.14632
33.9500633 35.1462667
33.9500633 35.1463
33.9500467 35.1462467
33.95004    35.1463333
33.9499167 35.1463533
33.94975  35.1464233
33.94981         35.1464533

these should fall approximately in the middle of the map.
Though, using the code you provided, the map stays in the middle of the cube, and points at the edge

Comment: The points are at the edge because that's where they are, though. Does it not work to just add your points? Parsing your dumped text here is painful, please use dput() and similar to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Oh, I forgot these maps are in web Mercator - it's only fitting it to the bounding box which is totally bogus. I'll clear the answer and fix.

Comment: well I want to have a basemap. it would do my work really. sorry for the messy text. I just don't know how to import data properly in the comments.
the point is that I have some coordinates and I want to plot them on a map in a 3D cube. the variables are lat, lon and time. so when I use your code, I do have the map at the bottom of the cube, but the points do not fall where they should. the map is in the middle, while the points are placed correctly. thanks for any help in advance

Comment: oh, I just saw your last comment. Yeah and update would be great really. thanks!